# Using Laplace Transform to solve this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How to solve this ODE, with Laplace Transform:

$$
\begin{cases}
20y'(x)+y(x)+4y''(x)=20\\
y(0)=10\\
4y'(0)=-2
\end{cases}
$$

Thanks in advance.

---

My work:

$$20y'(x)+y(x)+4y''(x)=20\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{t}\left[20y'(x)+y(x)+4y''(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_{t}\left[20\right]_{(s)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$20sy(s)-y(0)+y(s)+4s^2y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)=\frac{20}{s}$$

Comment: I would say: Install y(0)=10, y'(0)=-1/2 and express $y(s) = \cdots$. Control program WolframAlpha:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplace+transform+20y%27%2By%2B4y%27%27%3D20%2C+y%280%29%3D10%2C+y%27%280%29%3D-1%2F2

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Let $Y(s)$ be the Laplace transform of $y(t)$.

The last step should actually read:

$20sY(s) - 20y(0) + Y(s) + 4s^2Y(s) -4sy(0) - 4y'(0) = \frac{20}{s}$

Now lets find an expresion for $Y(s)$:

$Y(s)(4s^2 + 20s +1) = \frac{20}{s} + 20y(0) + 4sy(0) + 4y'(0)$

Simplify: $Y(s) = \frac{20 +198s+40s^2}{s(4s^2 + 20s +1)} = \frac{40s}{4s^2 + 20s +1} + \frac{198}{4s^2 + 20s +1} + \frac{20}{s(4s^2 + 20s +1)}$

Note: $4s^2 + 20s +1 = (2s+5)^2 - 24$. Now using [Laplace transform table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) you can easily transform $Y(s)$ back to $y(t)$ using 19, 20 and 32.

This is a fairly brute force approach to the problem, but never the less it works.